# Delete cookie button for W3 school cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Yes I know W3school, you all hate it. I do too at times but it is helping me now.
How do you make a delete cookie button for their website?
The cookie example that they have on their website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}

function checkCookie()
{
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + user);
  }
else 
  {
  user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (user!="" && user!=null)
    {
    setCookie("username",user,30);
    }
  }
}

</script></head>

<body onload="checkCookie()"></body>
</html>
```

I have tried to delete it using:

```
<input type="button" value ="delte cookie" onclick= '"document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";'/>
```

but it does not delete the cookie.
I have tried other ways to delete cookies of one site but they do not work.
Does anyone have html for a button that deletes the cookie of that site?

Comment: There are too many double quotes `"` in the onclick code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
 <input type="button" value ="delete cookie" onclick= 'document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";'/>
```

Comment: @user2330624, Yes. You may have missed to add that.!

Answer (score 1):

Found this a long time ago.... it works like a charm.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function on delete cookie button's onclick event

```
function delete_cookie(name){
document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```